# Downloading a video file using PHP

Tags: php

If you download an Youtube video using Internet Download Manager(IDM) you get the actual download url from properties>address and the url looks like following.

http://r8---sn-o097zne6.c.youtube.com/videoplayback?cp=U0hVTlFMVF9GU0NONV9JRlhFOk12VEU5YTJHQ0hS&expire=1369116419&fexp=934400%2C912519%2C930806%2C914010%2C916625%2C910822%2C924605%2C901208%2C929123%2C929915%2C929906%2C925714%2C929919%2C929119%2C931202%2C932802%2C928017%2C912518%2C911416%2C906906%2C904476%2C919373%2C906836%2C933701%2C900345%2C926403%2C912711%2C929606%2C910075%2C906098&id=16e6330cce76eecc&ip=74.115.0.148&ipbits=8&itag=22&key=yt1&ms=au&mt=1369093406&mv=m&newshard=yes&ratebypass=yes&signature=602A934CA39B8ECB2B324F56A280332ED5679A8B.2D2BF1C7A3E8B2139A4566198AFD3A3BAEEAC47F&source=youtube&sparams=cp%2Cid%2Cip%2Cipbits%2Citag%2Cratebypass%2Csource%2Cupn%2Cexpire&sver=3&upn=89uxLgRVS_U&cpn=8pfKhlVRglcZw_W9

if I put the following code in a file and click "Save As" the video starts downloading.

```
<a href="$link">Download Video</a> // $link = the above link
```

Now I have a file called video.php. What I am trying to do is when I will run the video.php file my code will start downloading the video from the url (like above url) automatically. Is this even possible?  If then could you please tell me how to do that?

I have tried to download using PHP but the page keeps loading and loading and does not show anying. The code I tried is following:

```
 $ch = curl_init ($link); // $link = the above link
 curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
 curl_exec ($ch);
```

Comment: Generally javascript isn't allowed to save files on the filesystem. There are exceptions though such as the new HTML5 filesystem apis, though i doubt that's really what you want.

Comment: @KevinB  Thank you for your reply. I have edited my question,title and also the tags :)

Comment: IDM download is working with new Youtube? Since when?

Comment: Yes its working. I just downloaded some videos few minutes ago. :)

Comment: Have you seen that virus from SweetPack IM or whatever? It was in IDM few months ago...

Comment: No I haven't seen any virus.. My IDM is working perfectly and haven't faced any problem with it so far :)

Answer (score 0):

Since direct connection to videos on port 80 is forbidden you would need to use some other way. I can imagine using some kind of background RTMP streamer on port 554 which is usually open, since is used for Flash video as default.

RTMPDump can do the job -> http://rtmpdump.mplayerhq.hu/

Comment: Thanks for you reply. I visited the link but I don't understand what RTMPDump exactly does.

Answer (score 0):

```
$file_url = $_GET['link'];           // http://www.somedomain.com/test.mp4
header('Content-Type: video/mp4'); 
header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=\"" . basename($file_url) . "\""); 
readfile($file_url);
```

Comment: Code-only answers are discouraged. Please provide an explanation why and how your answer solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use php's `readfile()` funtion as @Divakarcool comment. The readfile() function reads a file and writes it to the output buffer. also make sure to sanitize the url before passing it to `readfile()` if you are receiving it from user end

```
$file_url = $_GET['link'];
// Some logic to sanitize url
header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=\"" . basename($file_url) . "\""); 
readfile($file_url);
```

Visit [exploit-db](https://www.exploit-db.com/papers/12883) to learn more about vulnerabilities of readfile()